# Create Hyperlink or Picture Column with C# (Format URL as Picture)

Tags: development, url, hyperlink, spfield, picture

I am creating a SharePoint list with C# and have created a "Hyperlink or Picture" field like so:

```
myList.Fields.add("Icon", SPFieldType.URL, true);
```

when I add an item to the list in SharePoint this field is displayed as a hyperlink. By editing the list settings in SharePoint, I can change the "Format URL as" option from "Hyperlink" to "Picture" and it works as desired.

[image]

How can I set the field to display as picture when creating the field programmatically?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to give you detailed code, but you have to set this property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurl.displayformat(v=office.15).aspx. So cast the field to SPFieldUrl and then set the property DisplayFormat and call Update()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use 'DisplayFormat`

```
SPFieldUrl fldURLImage = (SPFieldUrl)list.Fields.CreateNewField(SPFieldType.URL.ToString(), "Picture");
fldURLImage.DisplayFormat = SPUrlFieldFormatType.Image;
myList.Fields.Add(fldURLImage,SPFieldType.URL, true);
```